# How to set Bangla font to a TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi i am a Bangladeshi.
I am new in Android programming.
I have a EditText. I need to set Bangla on it.
what can i do.

```
<EditText android:id="@id+/title"
          android:width="fill_parent"
          android:height="200dp"
          android:text="ঘূর্ণিঝড় রোয়ানুর কারণে"
/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download your font and keep it in assets folder.
Write your text that you set to TextView in strings.xml in values folder

```
<string name="text_of_title">ঘূর্ণিঝড় রোয়ানুর কারণে</string>
```

Now add it to TextView
like this

```
<EditText android:id="@id+/title"
      android:width="fill_parent"
      android:height="200dp"
      android:text="@strings/text_of_title"/>
```

Now write java code to add the font to the TextView

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
String BANGLA_FONT_SOLEMAN_LIPI = "/SOLAIMANLIPI_22-02-2012.TTF";
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(con.getAssets(),
 BANGLA_FONT_SOLEMAN_LIPI);
title.setTypeface(tf);
```

Thats all. I hope you will enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:fontFamily="@font/kalpurush"
            android:background="@drawable/edborder"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="00" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.