# Unable to display translated text on text view

Tags: android, api, textview, translation

I am using ML kit's on device translation API to translate a text.Although the translation is working perfectly fine but I am unable to display the translated text in my text view.I tried using setText method but nothing is being displayed in text view.Everything is being displayed in the logcat.

I am working in Android Studio

edit:
This  shows the model being downloaded

```
 TranslatorOptions options =
                    new TranslatorOptions.Builder()
                            .setSourceLanguage(TranslateLanguage.ENGLISH)
                            .setTargetLanguage(TranslateLanguage.BENGALI)
                            .build();
            final Translator englishBengaliTranslator =
                    Translation.getClient(options);

            //DOWNLOAD THE MODEL
            DownloadConditions conditions = new DownloadConditions.Builder()
                    .requireWifi()
                    .build();
            englishBengaliTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded(conditions)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Object o) {

                                }

                                //@Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void v) {
                                    // Model downloaded successfully. Okay to start translating.
                                    // (Set a flag, unhide the translation UI, etc.)
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Model Downloaded.Translation will start ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    // Model couldn’t be downloaded or other internal error.
                                    // ...
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Model could not be Downloaded. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
```

In this snippet of the code I have called the translate function (as the model is now downloaded)

```
englishBengaliTranslator.translate(stringResult)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(
                            new OnSuccessListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Object o) {

                                }

                                //@Override
                                public void onSuccess(@NonNull String translatedText1) {
                                    textViewTranslatedText.setText(translatedText1);

                                }
                            })
                    .addOnFailureListener(
                            new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    // Error.
                                    // ...
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text could not be translated. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
```

I have used the setText function but still the translated text gets displayed in logcat and not in the textview(The translation works completely fine).How do I display it in my textView instead of logcat?Any leads would be helpful!

here is the image of logcat where translated text is displayed:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTBop.jpg)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would share some of your code

Comment: Yeah sorry I hope now it is much more clear

Comment: There is no Log.d() found in the code that you posted.

Comment: Yeah I know I haven't put a Log statement why is getting displayed there??

Comment: It could be something with the TextView too. Can you paste the XML code and also just make sure that the `translatedText1` is not actually empty before setting it.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418712/how-to-set-bangla-font-to-a-textview-in-android

Comment: Thanks! now the issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code,

```
englishBengaliTranslator.downloadModelIfNeeded(conditions)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Model downloaded successfully. Okay to start translating.
                // (Set a flag, unhide the translation UI, etc.)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Model Downloaded.Translation will start ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(
                new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Model couldn’t be downloaded or other internal error.
                        // ...
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Model could not be Downloaded. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

The above code does nothing. I have just removed the unnecessary interface.

But the below code does something. I mean it specifies the return type.

```
englishBengaliTranslator.translate(stringResult)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                if(textViewTranslatedText!=null)
                    textViewTranslatedText.setText(translatedText1);
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: translation Done but text view null");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                //Handle onFailure
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yess it worked I was forgetting to specify the type String.Thank you so much!